# How to add a class method at runtime for Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

***Objc runtime*** provides a function, `class_addMethod()`, to try adding an instance method at runtime.

Is there any function which could try adding an class method to a class at runtime? Or, how can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the method to the metaclass of the class. Every non-meta class is an instance of its metaclass, so a class method is really just an instance method of a metaclass.